# Create an alias of variable?

Tags: c++, alias

I got a dilemma about creating an alias of variable and need your kind help.

**Purpose**

My function takes two vector, but I want to ensure that that **vector variable "a" will refer to the longer one**. At the same time, **I don't want to copy the vector**. So, I use the reference to create an alias, but I got a dilemma.

**Situation 1**

The variable can not be seen since the variable is in if clause, but I need the if clause to know which is longer.....

```
vector<float> conv(const vector<float> &operand1, const vector<float> &operand2){


if (operand1.size() < operand2.size()){
     const vector<float> &a = operand2;
     const vector<float> &b = operand1;
}
else{
    const vector<float> &a = operand1;
    const vector<float> &b = operand2;
}
```

**Situation 2**

Declare the reference outside the if clause. Unfortunately, the reference has to be initialized when declared. However, I need the if clause to know which operand to declare it as.

```
vector<float> conv(const vector<float> &operand1, const vector<float> &operand2){

const vector<float> &a;
const vector<float> &b;

if (operand1.size() < operand2.size()){
     &a = operand2;
     &b = operand1;
}
else{
     &a = operand1;
     &b = operand2;
}
```

Is there any way getting around this?? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is this you want:

```
vector<float> conv(const vector<float>& op1, const vector<float>& op2) {
    const vector<float> &a = op1.size() < op2.size() ? op2 : op1; // the longer one
    const vector<float> &b = op1.size() < op2.size() ? op1 : op2; // the other
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would save the result of `<` to a local `bool` variable first, then use that variable in the `?:` operators, eg: `bool op1_is_less = op1.size() < op2.size(); const vector<float> &a = op1_is_less ? op2 : op1; const vector<float> &b = op1_is_less ? op1 : op2; ...`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just don't want to use another variable here cause any modern compiler will do the optimization.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is just what I need. : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers instead of references:

```
vector<float> conv(const vector<float> &operand1, const vector<float> &operand2)
{
    const vector<float> *a;
    const vector<float> *b;

    if (operand1.size() < operand2.size())
    {
        a = &operand2;
        b = &operand1;
    }
    else
    {
        a = &operand1;
        b = &operand2;
    }

    // use *a and *b as needed ...
}
```